# Thunderbird won't send email

Tags: thunderbird, mozilla

Out of sudden, my Thunderbird stopped sending e-mails. When I click the send button, nothing happens. The send button does absolutely nothing. No error messages whatsoever. It's like it doesn't even try to do anything. Restarting Thunderbird didn't help. It can receive, though. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: As you can still receive e-mail, you should check your outgoing SMTP server in your Account Settings.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue. Disabled the EDS contact integration add-on and that fixed the problem.

Comment: How I do that? Could you please be more verbose?

Comment: @Braiam: Not sure if you have already worked it out, but click the Tools menu, then Add-ons; this will open a new tab displaying add-ons and extensions and allowing you to search for new ones. Select the Extensions item on the left-hand side and then click the disable button for the EDS contact integration add-on. You will have to restart Thunderbird for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

With bugs, you should run ubuntu-bug thunderbird and report this issue.

Try the following to see if it fixes the issue: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/thunderbird-stable; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade -y`

Then restart Thunderbird and try to send a message.

Answer (score 0):

The extension Check and Send was the cause of my inability to send. I had recently needed to create a new profile as my prefs.js file was corrupt. After copying all my mail, calendar and contacts to the new profile this bug showed up.