# I cannot access Thunderbird ppa

Tags: 12.04, lts

I tried the suggestion given to this question:

[Thunderbird won't send email](https://askubuntu.com/questions/355688/thunderbird-wont-send-email)

but apt gave the following error:

Cannot access PPA (https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~mozillateam/+archive/thunderbird-stable) to get PPA information, please check your internet connection.

Of course, because I can post this, my internet connection is fine. Any suggestions?

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That PPA seems to no longer exist, see [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=911807).

That other answer you linked to basically suggested installing the newest stable version of Thunderbird, which may have been more up-to-date than the latest stable version in the official repos at that time. But apparently, now the thunderbird package is updated often enough in the official repos.

Along the lines of the idea suggested in that other thread, if you have a similar problem and want try upgrading Thunderbird to solve it, you may try the Thunderbird Beta PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/thunderbird-next
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install thunderbird
```

Be aware that this will install a beta version of thunderbird, with a higher potential for bugs.

Comment: I installed 14.04, with support until 2019. That means it will upgrade to newer version in the future? I'm also looking for a stable upgrade of it, but there isn't.

Comment: Do you mean Thunderbird from the official repos or from the [mozillateam/thunderbird-next](https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/thunderbird-next) PPA? For the official repos: Yes. Although most packages are not updated to newer versions any longer after a release (see [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software) for example), Thunderbird is a [MicroReleaseException](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates/MicroReleaseExceptions).

Comment: For the PPA: That's pretty much up to the [PPA maintainers](https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam), but this particular PPA is maintained by Ubuntu's [Mozilla Team](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MozillaTeam), and they also still maintain thunderbird packages for Precise (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with support until 2017), so I think there is a good chance that yes, you will get upgrades to newer versions in the foreseeable future here too.